# Windows Authentication not working in ASP.NET MVC 5 web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-express

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app and am trying to enable Windows Authentication. The development machine is Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS Express 8.0, Visual Studio 2013 & .NET Framework 4.5.

I get a 404 Not Found error when ever I browse the app. The app enters a redirect loop with **http://localhost:63455/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F**. Eventually the `ReturnUrl` ends up being very large as it gets appended to with each redirect.

My web.config looks like this:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  </system.web>
```

I've tried setting the **Anonymous Authentication** and **Windows Authentication** settings on the Development Server properties.

[image: Development Server Properties]

I've also tried adding the following `appSettings`:

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

**How can I get Windows Authentication working properly?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `ConfigureAuth` method in `Startup.Auth.cs` contained the following code which needed to be removed for **Windows Authentication**.

The code is used for **Forms Authentication** with **OWIN**.

```
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. Is there a way i can use cookie AND windows authentication? Basically i need to add additional claims using OWIN. But when Windows auth is enabled, it doesnt seem to allow adding claims.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up.  You don't HAVE to remove cookie authentication entirely, although i did remove the externalsignincookie.  Take a look at my project at https://github.com/vishnu4/AspNetMVC5WinAuth where I'm using OWIN and MVC5 to use windows authentication.  Hopefully this helps anyone else trying to get it to work.