# In MVC 5 How can I convert Forms Authentication to windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, forms-authentication

I already have a MVC 5 web application that uses sql server authentication.  I am only using AspNetUser and AspNetRole table from EntityFramework and rest are custom tables. Important custom table is UserGroupRole that joins AspNetUser,AspNetRole and a Custom table called UserGroup that user have access to.

How can I easily convert this to Windows (Active Directory) authentication and still retain logic that I currently have.

One part of solution I am thinking is that if I can use AspNetUser table to store Active Directory users without password then I can retain most of code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me.

[Windows Authentication not working in ASP.NET MVC 5 web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260283/windows-authentication-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc-5-web-app)

I was able to retain logic by still using AspNetUser table.

To get the windows logged in user name I used

> HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Split('\')[1]

I guess you can also use

> User.Identity.Name.Split('\')[1]